# Где отредактировать часть шаблона storefront wordpress'a?

Tags: wordpress

На скрине отметил: мне нужно убрать первую из трех кнопок, но понять не могу где это редактировать.
Спасибо заранее!

[image: скрин]

Comment: Дочерняя тема создана?

Comment: нет вроде, сразу установил сторфронт.

Comment: Вроде? Вы сначало разберитесь с файловой структурой, создайте дочку, а потом вопрос создавайте. Только после этого я вам подскажу. А так вы исправите и всё отвалится после обновления.

Comment: Не совсем понимаю причем тут дочерняя тема? Цель то какая преследуется, если я прошу помощи указать где находится эта часть шаблона.

Comment: Для того, чтобы при поиске нужного кода ничего не сломать)

Comment: ничего страшного, сайт пока на тестовом домене.

Comment: Тогда копируйте папку с темой себе, и ищите строку кода которая выводит родительский класс. Находите и правите. А скорее всего если тема платная и с themeforest, то надо лучше по рыться в настройках. Так как кодом править самый последний вариант.

Comment: @doox911 storefront - самая известная и бесплатная тема от WooCommerce

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В файле "./inc/woocommerce/storefront-woocommerce-template-functions.php"

в 619 строчке идет функция storefront_handheld_footer_bar() в которой создается это меню и там есть my-account

Comment: Спасибо! Ага, то что надо.